# Proper UI manipulation using Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am having issue with UI manipulation:

I have this code:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
el : '[data-container]',
ui : {
    something : '[data-something]'
},
```

Then I can use:

```
this.ui.something.show().
```

This is plain jQuery selector, which will disable all input elements within the div.

```
$("#something :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

I am trying to do the same thing using this.ui selector, but how do I pass `:input`?
If I use

```
this.ui.something.attr("disabled", true);
```

it disables the div, but not the elements inside it.

Some ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I am trying to fix it as we speak. Formatting is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an element actually has a data attribute of `data-something`,  `$('input',this.ui.something).attr(...)` should work. All that is doing is finding all inputs inside elements that have data-something attribute

http://jsfiddle.net/sailorob/pvntR/

Edit: Just to clarify further, comma delimiter in the selector like `jQuery(el1,el2)` is the same as using `jQuery(el2).find(el1)`;

Comment: Excellent Rob. It works!!! Cant vote for your answer yet. But as soon as I can I will return and do it!!!

Answer (score 0):

That selector is not correct, it should be `$("#something input")` and this selector should work in the View too

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ui.something.find("input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: This will not work as this.ui.something is merely a string, not a jquery selector.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, your code isn't very clear. Glad Rob found a solution for you though!